# JavaScript div fade in with differet opacity levels

Tags: javascript

So I asked this question a little while ago but never ended up getting this to work. Right now I have 10 divs that I need to fade in all at once but with different opacity values. I have been playing with it but am having no luck getting each to fade in with a different opacity. Right now I have it fading all of the boxes in at once to 100% opacity. I just need the different opacity values to work now. This is the original code but with the array added. No jquery please, tis needs to be core JavaScript only.

```
var color;

var count = 0;

var colorOpac = [0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2];

function init() {
    color = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    setInterval(fadeColor, 1000);

}

function fadeColor() {
    setInterval(fade, 50);
}

function fade() {
    for(i=0; i<color.length;i++){
     color[i].style.opacity = count;

}
    count = count + 0.01;
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Comment: *No jquery please* <- I liked this, though you can do that using pure CSS, would be kinda over killing though

Comment: Oh I know that, but for this specific example, it must be pure JavaScript. If it didn't have to be, I would have just used CSS. Since not everything is supported on each browser, it makes it easier to just use JS. Rather than having to add fall backs all of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a separate function module which handles the fade operation like below.

```
(function(window){

    function fadeManager(ele,opacity){
        this.opacity = 0;       
        this.opacityLimit = opacity;
        this.ele = ele;
        //console.log(this.ele,this.opacity);
        this.initFade();
    }

    fadeManager.prototype.initFade = function(){        
        this.interval = setInterval(this.fade, 50, this);       
    }

    fadeManager.prototype.fade = function(self) {
        console.log(self.ele,self.opacity);
        if(self.opacity < self.opacityLimit){
           self.ele.style.opacity = self.opacity;
           self.opacity = self.opacity + 0.01;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(self.interval);    
        }
    }

    window.fadeManager = fadeManager;
})(window);
```

Then change your code to below,

```
    var color;        
    var count = 0;

    var colorOpac = [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2];

    function init() {
        color = document.querySelectorAll(".box"); 
        for(i=0; i<color.length;i++){
            // this will init fade in operation.
            var fade = new fadeManager(color[i],colorOpac[i]);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", init,false);
```

[CodePEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KtzJk)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zLaZr/9/)

Comment: The only thing with that example is they still all fade in to 100% opacity. The divs all need to start out at 0 and fade in to their corresponding opacity value and stop when it reaches that value. So the final product should be all of the divs fading in together but stopping at different values, not all stopping at 100% opacity.

Comment: Yes that is working perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was interested. I also found a way to make it work with just the 3 functions after messing around with it a bit. Here it is!

```
var color;

var count = 0;

var colorOpac = [0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2];

function init() {
    color = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    setInterval(fadeColor, 1000);

}

function fadeColor() {
    setInterval(fade, 50);
}

function fade() {
    for(i=0; i <color.length;i++){

    if(count < colorOpac[i]){
        color[i].style.opacity = count;
    }
}
    count = count + 0.01;
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);`
```